# Can we add a header and footer from a plugin in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to add my own header and footer to a WordPress website and not sure if it is possible ? I tried and researched a lot and even used [wp_head action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) to insert my code but it's not for that purposes and it is inside head section of a page.

My question is can we add our own header from a plugin ? If yes, then how ? If not then any suggession to make it done.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you can't create your own header.php and footer.php in theme folder and need to only overwrite existed ones?

Comment: Actually, i want to add from plugin. Can not touch theme files for some reason. So, only way left is by plugin. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: [Overwrite theme file from plugin - WordPress Development Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/258032/135534).

Comment: @Akramulhaq see the answers and comments by the following links: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/282171/144565 , https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/294486/144565 , https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/258032/144565 , https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/111684/144565

Comment: Create a child theme

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your own code in your theme header.php and footer.php file or customize those file with your own code. This is best solution for you. After customize your files, you can backup those files based on theme update, so that you can you can get back your own code again.

Comment: My question is how to do this from plugin. I can do so from a theme file even by creating a child theme and no issue for theme update at all. But my question is I want to do sofrom a plugin. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it from a plugin.

First of all you must read some documentation:

- about action hooks
- get_header hook
- and wp-includes/general-template.php

with the above as toolbelt you can do it.

I can not understand why you want to make this. If you make a theme the header and footer is custom. If you working on existing theme make a child theme an make custom header and footer.

Home i helped!